# Angular material "start" and "none" alignment

Tags: flexbox, angular-material

I'm trying to understand the difference between the two alignment properties `start` and `none`. In the demo, both the result looks the same, but what's the difference? 
For example for this code:

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="none center">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
</div>
```

And

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="start center">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
</div>
```

When we should use `start` instead of `none` and vice versa? Here is the [link for demos](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment).

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `layout-align` set the CSS property `justify-content`, and since `none` reverts to default, which is `flex-start`, and so does `start`, both render the same result.

So if you want to be sure it is `flex-start`, choose `start`.